# how to show limited items in collection view from plist ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to load limited items from Plist in a collection view. In my plist, I have 30 items but I want to show only 3 or 4 at a time and on button click want to show next 3. any idea how to figure this out ?

Comment: You mean something like pagination ??

Comment: kind of pagination, actually I want to show limited items and on click event collection view load next items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@interface ViewController ()
 {
 int currentPage;
 int pagelimit;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
currentPage=0;
pagelimit=3;
 [self reloadData];

} 

 -(IBAction)nextBtnClicked:(id)sender;
{
      NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:NSLocalizedString(@"plistName", nil) ofType:@"plist"]];
currentPage=currentPage+3;
pagelimit=pagelimit+3;
if (currentPage>[arr count])
{
    currentPage=currentPage-3;
    pagelimit=pagelimit-3;
    return;

}
 [self reloadData];

}

 -(IBAction)previousBtnClicked:(id)sender;
{
      NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:NSLocalizedString(@"plistName", nil) ofType:@"plist"]];   
currentPage=currentPage-3;
pagelimit=pagelimit-3;
if (currentPage<[arr count]) {
    currentPage=currentPage+3;
    pagelimit=pagelimit+3;
    return;

}
[self reloadData];

}

-(void)reloadData
{
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:NSLocalizedString(@"plistName", nil) ofType:@"plist"]];
[dataArray removeAllObjects];
for (int i=currentPage; i<pagelimit; i++) {

    [dataArray addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
}
[collectionview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thats work pretty fine but 1 thing more to figure out. the method. -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  as we already remove all objects in reload method, so the data in cell not populated

Comment: in reload method we are adding new data into array and then reload collectionview..

Comment: I definitely done that way before if I have reputation of 15. restriction from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `.plist` files to a `NSArray`, and from there, you can specifically ask for the first `[0]` in the sequence, the seventh `[6]`, or even the thirtieth `[29]`.

As far asking for the first three items, use code similar to this

```
-(void)getThree {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSString *first = [array objectAtIndex:(0)%array.count];
NSString *second = [array objectAtIndex:(1)%array.count];
NSString *third = [array objectAtIndex:(2)%array.count];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", first, second, third); }
```

#### Note:

The `[0]` is always the first item in the set, because they like to start with `0`.

So basically whatever the number of the item in the set is, subtract 1 and put it in between brackets.

Comment: in this way, we need a lot of variables. suppose we have 500 items in plist, then what to do ?